# C# Equation Visual Editor for Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, editor, ms-word, equation

I want to create equations choosing symbols visually as in Microsoft Word(
[image: Like this way]
) for my Windows Form Application. For example, I can choose "sin x" and after write 90, I'll press calculate button and it will show 1. What I mean is I should write an equation choosing components and then I can get the answer parsing this equation.

Is there an API or library to create visual equations as in Microsoft Word for C# Windows Form Applications?

Comment: Are you familiar with LaTeX?  It isn't an equation editor, but it is very good at displaying equations entered in a form like `y = \frac{x+1}{x^2}`.  If you added buttons to help users who don't know LaTeX, it might look something like this site: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Comment: I know LaTeX but what I want is a bit different as you mention.

@TJHeuvel I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: Also your question isnt specific enough, and it lacks effort.

Comment: Would you be kind enough and share what you ended up using? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it, but a quick search turned up [Math Expression Editor Light](http://www.componentsource.com/products/math-expression-editor-light/index-gbp.html). Any use?